# Menu Drawer With ActionBar Tab using Fragment bug

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

hi I am implemented navigation drawer in my app but i can't figure out why navigation drawer appear below tabs. i implemented navigation drawer , tabs using fragment. i need to disappear tab when i will call another fragment. this two problems are i cant figure out.

in my fragment i have try too remove all tabs. when i am calling another fragment from the drawer in my app icon are are disappear but still tab bar appeared without title and icon. help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is hide the ActionBar using

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    ......
    ......

}
```

Comment: Nop i want hide only tab bar if i am calling another Fragment

Comment: Check which fragment is currently open in MainActivity. And if Fragment NewsFeed is open then apply the "HIDE ACTION BAR" code.